# How to add a configuration during Azure DEVOPS web extension installation?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

- I want to develop an azure devops web extension under the test plans
  navigation menu.
- I would like to have a configuration page (one text
  box for input and button for submit). This configuration page must be
  launched during the installation of the extension and this page
  should not be accessed from test plans

How can I do the configuration in Azure devops extension?

Answer (score 0):

> How to add a configuration during Azure DEVOPS web extension installation?

I am afraid there is no such configuration in Azure devops extension to add a configuration page during Azure DEVOPS web extension installation.

You could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

[image]